# Turning black and white image into black and transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am making a sticker for Macbook Pro. The image is of the Joker and it is in black and white. Now I wanna make it in black and transparent so that when I stick it to the back of the laptop you could still see the silver underneath. I included the image here and another one( Harry Potter) as a reference.

PS: can I get a step by step explanation since I am still just a beginner

Thanks a lot!!
M

[Harry Potter Pic[image: ][1]]

Comment: Are you sure your sticker printer prints with *both black and white ink*? If it only prints black (which is kind of the default), you don't need to make the background white. It will simply be the color of the sticker material (which, I presume, is transparent to begin with).

Comment: Also, not sure if it's relevant or not, but that picture is not from Harry Potter it is from Batman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Select > Color Range, use that color picker and click on white. On the Select dropdown, pick Highlights and then click Ok and Delete to remove the white. You will end up with something like this:

[image]

Since @joojaa brought using channels up, yes, you can even Ctrl+Click on the Grey channel, go back to your Layer and hit delete..you would pretty much end up with this:

[image]

Comment: Err cant you just take the channel as alpha and invert it. At least theres nothing that can go wrong with that method.

Comment: @joojaa You could do that too, but I thought why not give another method of doing this...and in this image I don't think something could go wrong and it takes about 20 seconds to do :)) You could directly Ctrl+Click on the Grey channel and go back to the layer and hit Delete and you would still get what he wants.

Comment: @joojaa I've made an update to my answer on how he could use the grey channel to achieve this ^^ Thank you .

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you pal !!

Answer (score 1):

Like @joojaa said in one of the comments, you could create a channel from the image

[image]

and then invert it like so:

[image]

Now you can load this channel as a selection in a new layer and fill with any colour you like and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to alt-click on the layer in the Layers panel to change it from a background layer to a normal layer. Then double-click on the layer in the layers panel to bring up the Layer Style screen. Alt-drag the right inner toggle on the **This layer** bar leftwards until the white disappears. (It helps to put a colored layer beneath temporarily to see what's happening.) Do not flatten the image; save as a PNG.

[image]